# When can we extend an equalizer to a cosimplicial resolution?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

In an abelian category with enough injectives, we can inductively construct injective resolutions for any given object $A$. More precisely, given a monic $m:A\to B_0$ with $B_0$ injective, we can fit it into a long exact sequence $0\to A \to B_0 \to B_1 \to \dots$ with each $B_n$ being injective, and if I recall correctly, this resolution is unique up to chain homotopy.

(Actually, there is nothing special about injectives: one could be using a condition such as "enough $F$-acyclic objects" for one's preferred functor $F$.)

Now let ${\mathcal C}$ be a semi-abelian category in the sense of Borceux-Bourn (examples include ${\sf Grp}$).
Suppose we have an equalizer $m:A \to B_0$ of a parallel pair of arrows $B_0\to B_1$. Are there general conditions or procedures that allow one to extend this diagram to an augmented cosimplicial object $A\to B_0 \to B_1\to B_2 \to \dots$?

(I have not typset all the arrows, but I hope the meaning of the question is clear.)

If it helps: in my intended application, there are not enough injective objects in ${\mathcal C}$ in the strict sense, but there is a class of objects which become injective (more-or-less) after embedding ${\mathcal C}$ faithfully in some ${\mathcal D}$, and we have enough ${\mathcal D}$-injective objects of ${\mathcal C}$ in this sense. So my $B_1$ can always be chosen of this form. On the other hand I am not sure if my starting equalizer can always be assumed to be ${\mathcal D}$-split, but I would still be interested in what can be said in that more particular case.

Comment: You can take a right Kan extension of your equalizer diagram to make it a cosimplicial diagram. This procedure constructs a minimal extension: throw in the required codegeneracies and nothing else.

Comment: @GregoryArone Thank you! I will have to go and swot up on my category theory (unfortunately I don't have my copy of Mac Lane to hand)